# Comparing (several) keys in a Python list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, list, compare, tuples

I guys!
I've been trying to write a Python-3 program that compare if the keys in a list of tuples appears more than three times.

Here is an example of my list:

```
my_list = [('Configs', 98602471),
     ('Linux_Server', 10137300),
     ('Job-1', 10137300),
     ('Job-2', 10137300),
     ('Job-3', 10137300),
     ('Catalog', 10256456),
     ('Configs', 98602471),
     ('Linux_Server', 100),
     ('Job-1', 101),
     ('Job-2', 102),
     ('Job-3', 103),
     ('Catalog', 10277555),
     ('Configs', 98602471),
     ('Linux_Server', 100),
     ('Job-1', 104),
     ('Job-2', 105),
     ('Job-3', 106),
     ('Catalog', 10297994)]
```

The list above represent the name of the Baculas's Job and the size of the job (in bytes).

Here is my attempt:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in my_list:
     d[k].append(v)

for key, d in d.items():
     print(key, d)
```

And this is the result:

```
Job-3 [10137300, 103, 106]

Job-1 [10137300, 101, 104] 

Catalog [10256456, 10277555, 10297994] 

Configs [98602471, 98602471, 98602471] 

Linux_Server [10137300, 100, 100] 

Job-2 [10137300, 102, 105]
```

I'll need that the results shows me only the job (or jobs) that theirs sizes is the same more than three times.
For example, in this case, I'll need that only print for me the following:

```
Configs [98602471, 98602471, 98602471]
```

As you can see above, the size (**98602471**) of the job "**Configs**" is the same at least three times.

I don't now if I'm making myself clear.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you really seem to want to do is to count the *pairs* in that list of yours. You can use the `Counter` object to do that, then look through its keys to find any items whose counts are not less than three.

```
my_list = [('Configs', 98602471),
    ('Linux_Server', 10137300),
    ('Job-1', 10137300),
    ('Job-2', 10137300),
    ('Job-3', 10137300),
    ('Catalog', 10256456),
    ('Configs', 98602471),
    ('Linux_Server', 100),
    ('Job-1', 101),
    ('Job-2', 102),
    ('Job-3', 103),
    ('Catalog', 10277555),
    ('Configs', 98602471),
    ('Linux_Server', 100),
    ('Job-1', 104),
    ('Job-2', 105),
    ('Job-3', 106),
    ('Catalog', 10297994)]

from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(my_list)

for count in counts:
    if counts[count]>=3:
        print (count, counts[count])
```

Result:

```
('Configs', 98602471) 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it might be possible to refactor:

```
for key, d in d.items():
     print(key, d)
```

into

```
for key, d in d.items():
    if len(set(d)) + 1 < len(d):
        print(key, d)
```

Obviously that is solution for the case when *only one element in the list duplicates* more then three times, and it would not work properly when several elements are the same several times:

```
[22, 22, 11, 11]  # not appropriate list view
```